# webpack errors with create-react-app & svgr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I created react app by using create-react-app and 2 days ago i run `npm run eject` follows by i added [@svgr/webpack](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/)
into project it was working perfectly at the time. I just get back to do some undone work, but when i run `yarn start` the error it's showed in the command:

```
options/query provided without loader (use loader + options) in {
  "test": [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  "use": [
    "@svgr/webpack",
    "url-loader"
  ],
  "options": {
    "limit": 10000,
    "name": "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
  }
}
```

follow the error message i change webpack.config.js to

```
{
  test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/, /\.svg$/],
  loader: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader'],
    options: {
      limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
      name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    },
  },
```

it then shows

```
options/query cannot be used with loaders (use options for each array item) in {
  "test": [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ],
  "loader": [
    "@svgr/webpack",
    "url-loader"
  ],
  "options": {
    "limit": 10000,
    "name": "static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]"
  }
}
```

Anybody have the workaround to solve this problem.

[Github issues](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/issues/374)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your configuration to

```
{
  test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/, /\.svg$/],
  use: [{
    loader: '@svgr/webpack',
    options: {
      limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
      name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    }
  },
  {
    loader: 'url-loader'
  }]      
},
```